# Implementing a Worker with success on the basis of liveData events

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-workmanager

This sounds like a basic thing but I can't figure out how to achieve it. I have a Worker class that does some tasks.

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public Worker.Result doWork() {
        //Some work that involves liveData 
        return Worker.Result.SUCCESS;
    }

@Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {    
        if(//Something){
            //If this happens only then should the Worker return success
        }else{
            //Else return Failure/Retry
        }
    }
```

I want to return success on the basis of the values returned by the liveData I have. I can't figure out how to do this. Can someone guide me. Thanks!!

Comment: You can use countdown latch to wait for live data result.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this question and why? At least mention the reason for downvote.

Comment: @JeelVankhede Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into this.

Comment: Yah, let me know if you need any help though.

Comment: @JeelVankhede Your approach did the trick. You can add it as an answer and I can accept if you wish. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **`CountDownLatch`** can fix issue for **Async calls** in Worker :

```
final WorkerResult[] result = {WorkerResult.RETRY};
CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);    

@NonNull
@Override
public Worker.Result doWork() {
    //Some work that involves liveData 
    try {
        countDownLatch.await(); // This will make our thread to wait for exact one time before count downs
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result[0];
}

@Override
public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {    
    if(//Something){
        //If this happens only then should the Worker return success
        result[0] = WorkerResult.SUCCESS;
    }else{
        //Else return Failure/Retry
        result[0] = WorkerResult.RETRY;
    }
    countDownLatch.countDown(); // This will count down our latch exactly one time & then our thread will continue
}
```

Checkout more from [**here**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch)

Comment: @varunkr please check my answer, let me know if any changes in it